# using php-openssl create digital signature for docx

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, digital-signature, php-openssl

i need to create digital signature for fillable form.It means that when user fill the forms, he has to sign the doc. with his own private key and our server will check his private key using public key. I researched it but i couldnt find true answer. I will use php-openssl and forms will be fillable. I can create a key pair with this code;

```
// generate 2048-bit RSA key    
$pkGenerate = openssl_pkey_new(array(

    'private_key_bits' => 2048,

    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA));

// get the private key    
openssl_pkey_export($pkGenerate,$pkGeneratePrivate);

// get the public key    
$pkGenerateDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkGenerate);

$pkGeneratePublic = $pkGenerateDetails['key'];

// free resources    
openssl_pkey_free($pkGenerate);

// fetch/import public key from PEM formatted string    
// remember $pkGeneratePrivate now is PEM formatted...    
// this is an alternative method from the public retrieval in previous

$pkImport = openssl_pkey_get_private($pkGeneratePrivate); // import

$pkImportDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkImport); // same as getting the public key in previous

$pkImportPublic = $pkImportDetails['key'];

openssl_pkey_free($pkImport); // clean up

echo "\n".$pkGeneratePrivate

    ."\n".$pkGeneratePublic

    ."\n".$pkImportPublic

    ."\n".'Public keys are '.
(strcmp($pkGeneratePublic,$pkImportPublic)?'different':'identical').'.';
```

Comment: i couldnt add my code . my question is ; how can i integrate my key pair to docx

Comment: Well, we need to see code to fix code. I'd recommend trying to add your code again. All you have to do is have one blank line before the code, and make sure every line of code is indented at least 4 spaces.

Comment: "... [sign] with his own private key and our server will check his private key using public key..." - a lot of the browser support to do this is missing. For example, generating the private key and storing it with an Origin Policy so the web service/server can retrieve it. The [WebCrypto](http://www.w3.org/2012/webcrypto/) Working Group is working on that now.